# Maximized form with borderstyle set to none is cut with docked onscreen keyboard

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a simple form with the properties set:

```
WindowState := wsMaximized;
BorderStyle := bsNone;
```

I have also placed a button on the bottom of the form (anchored to the bottom).
I run the application and I have the whole form on the entire screen.

Then I run onscreen keyboard: (Start->Run: tabtip) and dock it to the bottom.

The form is lifted up to the border of the keyboard but it is slightly trimmed, that's why the Button is trimmed a little.

What can I do to alleviate the problem?